# Indesign script (javascript) on key press

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, onkeypress

This is a fairly straight forwards question, but I cannot find the answer in the documentation.

I know it is possible to detect clicks, but is it possible to detect a key press using an InDesign script?

For example, if the user creates a text box, and types 'a' into it, I would like to capture that and do something with it.

Perhaps this can be done using hotkeys, where for example one script on startup adds a hotkey for each keyboard button, each hot key fires a script for handling it. This seems a bit of a hack (if it would even work). Is there not a on key press listener I can add?

Any help is much appreciated.

I have found this so far in the documentation:

> Most of the things scripting cannot do—like setting up a workspace or
>   defining a set of keyboard  shortcuts—are things that have to do with
>   the user interface.

Comment: eventListener is the one what comes to mind, but I don't think there is one to trigger on key press.

Comment: OK, there is AFTER_CONTEXT_CHANGED event. You might try to combine with eventListener on a text frame and check the last character entered.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example you give (typing something into a text frame), you can use the afterSelectionChanged event listener (whose parent can be the application, or a layout window, amongst others).